# search a string from a file in shell script program and paste the string to another file

Tags: shell

Search a string from a file in **shell script program** and paste the string to another file.

This is what i used in command prompt :
**ps -ef | grep stringname inputfilename > outputfilename**

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. 

Please format your question, provide an example of what you have and what you are trying to get as result.

What's wrong with your solution? It seems correct

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i want to search a particular string from a file and copy then copy the whole line to another file, which is already done in command prompt. but now i want it should execute in program, where i can call the script and the code should run

Comment: Just create an .sh file with that command and execute it from its location..

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
cat filename | grep stringname > other file
```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly do

```
grep -i "StringName" <fileName> > other file
```

i - represents case sensitive of the string.

Answer (score 0):

NOTE: - If you are new to shell, you can create a shell file `test.sh` and run below mentioned command via `sh test.sh`.

`grep -w -i stringname inputfilename > outputfilename`

Explanation of options:-

`-w` -> match word only

`-i` -> ignore case

Input file

> X_ID1test y_id11 num1
>
> **X_ID1** test y_id11 num1

grep -w -i "X_ID1" inputfile > outputfile

It will match **X_ID1** only 2nd line only will be saved to outputfile. Without `-w` option it will match 1st line also.